# SharedPreferences sent by ACRA are all empty

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, acra

I followed the manual for implementing SharePreferences capture inside ACRA. What I basically did was including the following line in the configuration (is one of the lines of the complete configuration:

```
  customReportContent = { APP_VERSION, 
                       ANDROID_VERSION,
                       SHARED_PREFERENCES }
  additionalSharedPreferences={"EXTRA_MESSAGE","NOTIF_ACTIVATED"}
```

I followed the information from [this manual](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#adding-custom-sharedpreferences-names) and the details [on this one](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/ReportContent#shared_preferences) .

However, all the preferences I received in my Cloudant database appear as empty. I made sure that ALL variables are not the default variables, specially on this 2 ones, which are changed earlier in the configuration, I tricked my code just before the message changing intentionally those variables. But, I am still receiving empty values.

I order to double check I included the email option to check what data was written by ACRA, also filling the field empty. The evidences I have:
- Report at Clound Ant with SharedPreferences are empty.
- The email text introduced by ACRA and offered to the user is also having the field as "empty".
- No error output from ACRA in any operation

After investigating during the morning I am blocked and I don't know what else to do.

SDK21 and ACRA4.5.0 using a 2.3 android mobile.

Comment: You mention that the values that appear it you Cloud Ant DB are empty, but what comes across the wire? What does the values of the SHARED_PREFERENCES or ?additionalSharedPreferences field look like in the Request?

Comment: Appart from the trick I used this morning of activating the email (added in my response) is there any way to increase the logs provided by ACRA so I can provide further info? The shared_preferences in the request are the ones I show you. I intentionally reduced it to 2 in my tests to avoid other errrors.

Comment: You misunderstood. Post the values of the request as it hits your server. I suspect the values may be getting there but your server code is ignoring them.

Comment: Um... that doesn't explain why when I activate in ACRA to send by mail the values they are also empty. I think both problems are related, aren't they?

Comment: Sounds likely - raise an issue.

Comment: Done, we will see...probably the conclusion of this request is that there is a bug and we can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a wrong usage of SharePreferences in ACRA and not actually a bug in ACRA.

When the SharedPreferences is instantiated is a good practice to create a dedicated file using a code line like this one:

```
  String MyPREFERENCES = "MYPREFS";
  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In this case "MyPREFENCES" will be the new preferences name. In order to properly use ACRA this new file needs to be explicitly added in the ACRA configuration using the following:

```
additionalSharedPreferences={"MYPREFS"}
```

The problem I was having was that I included the fields that I included in my shared preferences and NOT the preferences file that I created. Just adding the proper filename everything was working ok.